# Update hadoop hadoop-2.6.5 to haddop 3.x. Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby

Tags: hdfs, namenode, datanode

update hadoop from hadoop-2.6.5 to 3.x

1.I put the new version package into a folder. copy the config files to the new folder, then shut down the old version service.

2. start up new version service. alert me to format the namenode,i am afraid to make mistakes,  then I shut down the new sevice.
3. I return to the old version, then start the old version, alterting me datanode version layoutid is not consistent. then i change the expected versionId to -56. the old serice then starts up.

the errors is as follow.

2024-03-27 10:32:17,398 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Can't replicate block BP-1203938771-192.168.0.181-1606981736566:blk_1141104833_67399052 because the block file doesn't exist, or is not accessible
2024-03-27 10:32:20,393 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Failed to report bad block BP-1203938771-192.168.0.181-1606981736566:blk_1342861671_269161413 to namenode :  Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1727)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1352)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.reportBadBlocks(FSNamesystem.java:6983)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.reportBadBlocks(NameNodeRpcServer.java:737)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.reportBadBlocks(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:27343)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.reportBadBlocks(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.reportBadBlocks(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.reportBadBlocks(BPServiceActor.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.reportBadBlocks(BPOfferService.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.reportBadBlock(DataNode.java:1816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.transferBlock(DataNode.java:1856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.transferBlocks(DataNode.java:1888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.processCommandFromActive(BPOfferService.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.processCommandFromActor(BPOfferService.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.processCommand(BPServiceActor.java:923)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:889)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

block BP-1203938771-192.168.0.181-1606981736566:blk_1141104833_67399052 exists in the datanode.
the file can not be downloaded from the webbrowser.